# Unrolling nested loops c++

Tags: c++, intel-ipp, loop-unrolling

I'm trying to unroll a nested loop that stores data in a 2D dynamic memory allocation in C++. Although, I'm not quite sure how to do it. Here is my original loop before unrolling:

```
int steps[1]; 
Ipp32f* vectx = ippiMalloc_32f_C1(size0, size1, &(steps[0])); 

for (int i = 0; i < size0; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < size1; j++){
        Ipp32f* pointer = (Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + steps[0]*j + sizeof(Ipp32f)*i); 
        *pointer = datax[i]; 
    }
}
```

datax is an array with values, size0 = 30 and size1 = 10000 in my program.
I tried the following but unfortunately the values are not the same at each position. Could someone help me?

```
for (int i = 0; i < size0; i+=4) {
     for (int j = 0; j < size1; j+=4) {
        *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx+ (steps[0] * j +0)+ (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i ))) = datax[i];
        *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 1) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i ))) = datax[i ];
        *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 2) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i ))) = datax[i ];
        *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 3) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i ))) = datax[i ];
     }
     for (int j = 0; j < size1; j += 4) {
        *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 0) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i+1))) = datax[i+1];
        *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 1) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i+1))) = datax[i+1];
        *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 2) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i+1))) = datax[i+1];
        *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 3) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i+1))) = datax[i+1];
     }

     for (int j = 0; j < size1; j += 4) {
         *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 0) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i + 2))) = datax[i + 2];
         *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 1) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i + 2))) = datax[i + 2];
         *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 2) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i + 2))) = datax[i + 2];
         *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 3) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i + 2))) = datax[i + 2];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size1; j += 4) {
         *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 0) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i + 3))) = datax[i + 3];
         *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 1) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i + 3))) = datax[i + 3];
         *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 2) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i + 3))) = datax[i + 3];
         *((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 3) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i + 3))) = datax[i + 3];
    }

}
```

Comment: Judging by the ssteps[0] the code isn't even compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not taking in account operator precedence

```
*((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * j + 1) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * i+1))) = datax[i+1];
                                        ^^^^^^--here               ^^^--and here
```

you should add `()`

```
*((Ipp32f*)((Ipp8u*)vectx + (steps[0] * (j + 1)) + (sizeof(Ipp32f) * (i+1)))) = datax[i+1];
                                        ^^^^^^                        ^^^
```

Obviously you should do this in all the rows

And BTW, `size0 = 30`, if you unroll the loop 4 by 4, you will go out of bound during the last iteration of the first loop, you should use a multiple of `size0`, like 5 or 6

Comment: @Melissa please read the note that i have just added at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Better use this C++20 unrolling helper:

```
#pragma once
#include <utility>
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>

template<size_t N, typename Fn>
    requires (N >= 1) && requires( Fn fn, size_t i ) { { fn( i ) } -> std::same_as<void>; }
inline
void unroll( Fn fn )
{
    auto unroll_n = [&]<size_t ... Indices>( std::index_sequence<Indices ...> )
    {
        (fn( Indices ), ...);
    };
    unroll_n( std::make_index_sequence<N>() );
}

template<std::size_t N, typename RandomIt, typename UnaryFunction>
    requires std::random_access_iterator<RandomIt>
    && requires( UnaryFunction fn, typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type elem ) { { fn( elem ) }; }
inline
RandomIt unroll_for_xeach( RandomIt begin, RandomIt end, UnaryFunction fn )
{
    RandomIt &it = begin;
    if constexpr( N > 1 )
        for( ; it + N <= end; it += N )
            unroll<N>( [&]( size_t i ) { fn( it[i] ); } );
    for( ; it < end; ++it )
        fn( *begin );
    return it;
}
```